# Did I show correctly that $0$ is null recurrent or did I produce nonsense?

Tags: markov-chains

> > Suppose that you have a Markov chain with state space $E$ containing $0$. Assume that
> >     $$
> > p_{00}^{(2n)}=\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-1}~~~\text{ and }~~~p_{00}^{(2n-1)}=0~~~\text{ for }n\in\mathbb{N}.
> > $$
> >     Is $0$ transient, positive recurrent or null recurrent?

Already showed that $0$ is recurrent.

Claim: $0$ is null recurrent.

Therefore have to show $E_0(t(0))=\infty$, where $t(0)$ is the first return time of $0$.

Question: Is it right that
$$
P_0(t(0)=2k)=\frac{1}{k}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k-1}?
$$

I continued with the following:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_0(t(0))&=\sum_{k\geq 1}2k\cdot\underbrace{\mathbb{P}_0(t(0)=2k)}_{=\frac{1}{k}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}\\
&=1+2\sum_{k\geq 2}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k-1}.
\end{align}

Using Stirling's formula $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ I get
\begin{equation*}
1+2\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi (k-1)}}\cdot 2^{2(k-1)}\cdot \frac{2}{2^{2k}}=1+\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi (k-1)}}=1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}\geq 1+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k}=\infty.
\end{equation*}
Thus $\mathbb{E}_0(t(0))=\infty$. That is $0$ is null recurrent.

Comment: As has already been mentioned to you ([rather exhaustingly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18675/discussion-on-question-by-mathfemi-is-0-transient-positive-recurrent-or-null)), (1.) your formula for $p_{00}^{(2n)}$ is bogus and (2.) there is no need to compute $P_0(t(0)=2k)$ to determine null/positive recurrence (as explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1022964/6179)). Regarding the question explicitely stated here, namely, to confirm whether your formula for $P_0(t(0)=2k)$ is correct or not, note that you produce zero motivation/explanation for this formula. .../...

Comment: .../... Explaining how you reached it is mandatory (and nearly everything else in the current question is actually offtopic). Until then, this question should be closed for "lack of context".

Comment: @Did I do not know what you mean with that my formula for $p_{00}^{(2n)}$ is bogus, which formuly do you mean?

Comment: ?? The only formula starting with $p_{00}^{(2n)}=...$ in this post. // Listen, you will not drag me into another morass of a convoluted discussion where you basically never answer what I say. Hence, this is my last comment here.

Comment: Okay, but this formula is given in the task is not my result.

Comment: Ok, I try to explain how I got the formula for $P_0(t(0)=2k)$. I looked how many ways there are starting in 1 going back to 1 in 2k-2 steps (2 steps are reserved for going from 0 to 0 and then in the end going back from 1 to 0) and which probability each such way has.